# Azure Devops Branch filter with wild card not working

Tags: azure-devops

In the build definition under trigger > continuous integration when I select a branch with wildcard Feature/* it does not trigger a build but when I specify a specific build Feature1 then it does trigger

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will only work if you name your branch `Feature/Feature1` or change the filter to `Feature*`.